# Chrome's auto-hiding URL bar is messing up my background gradient

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

This issue is specific to Chrome running under Android (possibly iOS, I didn't test).

I'm trying to get a simple gradient to cover the entire page height and remain fixed while other page elements are scrolling.

Everything works well until chrome for Android auto-hides the URL bar at the top as you scroll down.
At that point, a portion of the background, equivalent to the URL bar's height turns white at the bottom of the page.

Any ideas on how to avoid this issue and maintain my gradient across the entire page?

Pseudo HTML:

```
<html><head></head>
<body class="menu_body">
[Some scrollable content]
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_body {
  color            : #fff; 
  background       : linear-gradient( 130deg, rgb(44,49,65) 0%, rgb(94,67,70) 100%);
  height           : 100%;
  margin           : 0px;
  padding          : 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I know is is a little hacky, but it might work: https://dev.to/peiche/100vh-behavior-on-chrome-2hm8

Comment: @JeremyHarris I read that, From the comments there,I tried to also set the height to 100% in the <head> section, but it didn't make a difference. I didn't try the suggested solution as I'm not running wordpress and I'm not sure how to make it work clean.